# How long after drinking alcohol is it safe to eat durian again?

Tags: food-safety, alcohol, liver, fruits, food-poisoning

I read on {1}:

> This study provides evidence that some component(s) of durian fruit inhibit(s) yALDH in vitro. Inhibitory action of the non-polar sulfury constituents of the fruit like diethyl disulfide on yALDH, with further investigation, offers a novel rationale to the etiology of the durian-alcohol anecdote. As such, work on this theme is currently undertaken to confirm the bioactive component(s) in the durian fruit, and validate the consistency of the findings hereby reported in mammalian models in vivo.

Simplified summary: don't mix durian and alcohol.

How long after drinking alcohol is it safe to eat durian again?

---

I have crossposted the question at:

- [Quora](https://qr.ae/pNySO7)
- [Reddit](https://redd.it/gqhr6s)

---

References:

- {1} Maninang, John S., Ma Concepcion C. Lizada, and Hiroshi Gemma. "Inhibition of aldehyde dehydrogenase enzyme by Durian (Durio zibethinus Murray) fruit extract." Food chemistry 117, no. 2 (2009): 352-355. https://doi.org/10.1016/j.foodchem.2009.03.106

Comment: ELI5 is Reddit-speak. You might want to spell out acronyms on first use here.

Comment: @CareyGregory ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This inability to mix durian with alcohol has the status of a food myth. To quote the dietetic department at Changi Hospital

> 3. Eating durian and drinking beer at the same time may kill you
>
> There is no scientific evidence to show that this is a lethal combination. It is more likely to cause bloating, indigestion and discomfort as your liver has to work extra hard to metabolise both fats and sugars in the durians and the alcohol, especially if you have consumed both in excessive amounts.

Note also that the paper you quoted says in vivo studies failed to support a relationship.

In any case if you wanted to avoid a possible disulfiram reaction it depends on how much alcohol has been consumed, and your metabolism. And you can check with a breath alcohol analyser

https://www.healthxchange.sg/food-nutrition/food-tips/durian-myths-alcohol-cholesterol

Comment: Thanks for the information!